# SVN Mergeinfo stored on WC or on Server

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-merge

Kindly clarify my questions.  I ask these question because I'd like to understand the reason for 'missing mergeinfo'

```
1)  Is svn:mergeinfo stored on 'SVN Host Server' or on 'Working copy'? 
2)  If svn:mergeinfo is stored on 'Serverside'  is there any log file or something like that to go through it ?
3)  If svn:mergeinfo is stored on 'WC' how it's synced when different users 'checks out' the repository
```

Answer (score 0):

`svn:mergeinfo` is a meta-data property which is attached to a file or directory and is therefore transferred to the repository. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html More information about properties in general: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html